# Add Websocket handler from Redux-Toolkit Slice onQueryStarted callback

Tags: websocket, redux-toolkit

I am migrating my project to Redux-Toolkit and part of that working on WS based notification. Here is my RTK implementation as par current design

My websocket client with handler.

```
import { OPEN } from '@/constants/websocket'
/**
 * @const {number} maxAttempts - max retries for initial connection
 */
const maxAttempts = 10
/**
 * @function createHandlers
 * @description sets event handlers for websocket instance
 * @param {Websocket} instance
 */
const createHandlers = instance => {
    /**
     * @function onopen
     * @description updates Websocket class attributes on open
     * @param {Event} event
     */
    instance.connection.onopen = event => {
        instance.connected = true
    }
    /**
     * @function onclose
     * @description updates Websocket class attributes on close and re-establishes connection
     *  if closure was not intended
     * @param {Event} event
     */
    instance.connection.onclose = event => {
        instance.connected = false

        if (!instance.terminated) {
            instance.connection = new WebSocket(instance.path)
            createHandlers(instance)
        }
    }
    /**
     * @function onerror
     * @description loggs error to console if one occurs
     * @param {Event} event
     */
    instance.connection.onerror = event => {
        console.error(`Socket: ${instance.socketName}: Error ${event.message}`, event)
    }
    /**
     * @function onerror
     * @description passes incoming messages to the handler
     * @param {MessageEvent} message
     *
     * @returns {*}
     */
    instance.connection.onmessage = message => instance.handler(message)
}
/**
 * @class Websocket
 * @description handler for browser websocket implmentation
 */
export default class Websocket {
    /**
     * @constructor
     * @param {string} _socketName
     * @param {string} _path
     * @param {function} _handler
     */
    constructor(_socketName, _path, _handler) {
        this.path = _path
        this.handler = _handler
        this.socketName = _socketName || 'newSocket'
        this.connection = new WebSocket(_path)
        this.connected = false
        this.terminated = false
        createHandlers(this)
    }
    /**
     * @function open
     * @description execution of this function completes when websocket is open
     *
     * @returns {Promise}
     */
    open() {
        let attempt = 0

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const interval = setInterval(() => {
                console.log(`[LO websocket client]: attempting to open ${this.connected} ${this.connection.readyState}`, `${this.connection.id}`)
                if (this.connected && this.connection.readyState === OPEN) {
                    clearInterval(interval)

                    return resolve(true)
                }

                if (attempt === maxAttempts) {
                    clearInterval(interval)

                    return reject('[LO websocket client]: timeout reached')
                }

                ++attempt
            }, 1000)
        })
    }
    /**
     * @function send
     * @description transmits a request to the websocket server
     *
     * @returns {Promise}
     */
    send(payload) {
        this.connection.send(JSON.stringify(payload))
    }
    /**
     * @function terminate
     * @description allows an authorised closure of the websocket that wont invoke a
     * new instance.
     *
     * @returns {Promise}
     */
    terminate() {
        this.terminated = true

        this.connection.close()
    }
    /**
     * @function info
     * @description provides data on an active websocket implentation
     *
     * @returns {WebSocket}
     */
    info() {
        return this.connection
    }
}
```

Here is my notification service for WS. Adds the `fetchNotificationsCallback` RTK query as WS handler to process incoming WS messages.

```
import config from '../config/default'
import Websocket from './websocket'
/**
 * @function handler
 * @description passes incoming notification messages to the store
 * @param {MessageEvent} message
 *
 * @returns {Store}
 */
const SOCKET_PATH = config.apiWebsocket

/**
 * @class Notifications
 * @description handles the websocket communications and events for in app notifications.
 */
export default class Notifications {

  /**
   * @constructor
   */
  constructor(authorId, fetchNotificationsCallback) {
    // const user = useSelector((state) => state.application.user);
    this.authorId = authorId;
    this.params = `?authorId=${this.authorId}`
    this.name = 'notificationWebsocket'
    this.fetchNotificationsCallback = fetchNotificationsCallback;
    this.handleMessage = this.handleMessage.bind(this)
    this.websocket = new Websocket(
      this.name,
      SOCKET_PATH + this.params,
      this.handleMessage
    )
  }
  handleMessage(message) {
    const parsed = JSON.parse(message.data)
    console.log('received message', parsed)
    if (parsed.action === notificationActionTypes.REFRESH) {
      console.log('received message meet condition', parsed)
      this.fetchNotificationsCallback();
    }
  }

  /**
   * @async
   * @function open
   * @description resolves promise once the websocket is in OPEN state
   *
   * @returns {bool}
   */
  async open() {
    return await this.websocket.open()
  }


  /**
   * @function info
   * @description surfaces information about the current websocket session
   *
   * @returns {WebSocket}
   */
  info() {
    return this.websocket.info()
  }
}
```

And then notification RTK slice which hosts the `fetchNotifications` query and `onQueryStarted` callback initializes the WS and passes the `fetchNotifications` as an parameter. And calls the WS `open` to resolve the connection status for open with retry.

```
export const notificationApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'notificationApi',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: `${url}`,
    prepareHeaders,
  }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    fetchNotifications: builder.query({
      query: (pageNumber) => {
        const pageSize = PAGE_SIZE

        return {
          url: 'notifications',
          params: { pageNumber, pageSize },
        }
      },
      transformResponse: (response) => {
        if (!response.data) {
          return response
        }
        response.data = response.data.map((item) => mapNotification(item))
        return response
      },
      transformErrorResponse: (response) => {
        console.error(response.error)
        return response.status
      },
      onQueryStarted: async (_, { dispatch, queryFulfilled, getState }) => {

        const user = getState().application.user;
        if (user) {
          const notificationsHandler = new Notifications(user.id, async () => {
           await notificationsHandler.open();
           // Trigger the fetchNotifications query
           return await dispatch(notificationApi.endpoints.fetchNotifications.initiate(1, { queryFulfilled }));
      });

          // await notificationsHandler.open();
          console.log('notificationsHandler', notificationsHandler)
        }

      }
    })
  }),
})
export const { useFetchNotificationsQuery} = notificationApi
```

I am calling `useFetchNotificationsQuery` part of initial component rendering. And the expecting is it will start the WS connection. I can see the connection is happening in console `connection status` but somewhere the handler binding to WS is not happening the that eventually unable to process an incoming WS messages.

Interesting observation, if I just recall the `useFetchNotificationsQuery.refetch` from some event then things started working as expected. But not working part of initial rendering.